# How to write regexp which will validate the following strings?

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox, qregexp, qvalidator

I have tried following regexp in cpp `^((T[X-Z]|R[X-Z])+?)(?:,\\s*|$)`. It validates only TX. If empty string it should be invalid, it should not accept numbers as well

User may enter:

1. TX
2. TX, TY
3. TX, TY, TZ,
4. RX, RY, RZ
5. RX

It should be valid in all cases.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What happens on what input, and what did you expect to happen instead? Can you also [edit] your question and provide your code as a [mcve]? See [ask].

Comment: ^((T[X-Z]|R[X-Z])+?)(?:,\\s*|$), this regexp accepts only TX, nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the test cases that you put here,`([TR][XYZ])(,( )?)?` might work.

I have tested it for you [here](http://regexr.com/54bi3) (Mention that `global` and `multiline` flags are enabled)

Comment: an empty string should be invalid, any suggestions?

Comment: the `?` denote that it could wither appear once or no times.
If you decide that you want it to appear exactly once just remove the `?`
If you want it to be 1 or many times change the `?` to `+`

Anyway I really suggest that you will use a tool like: https://regex101.com/
You can test your regex there.

Comment: (T[X-Z]|R[X-z]+?)(?:,\s*|) this regexp works but it accepts a number and then it shows it is invalid, but I don't want to accept numbers

Comment: @nehamundokar It doesn't capture white spaces, so for checking `an empty string should be invalid`, in your program check it. (Whether is it `null` or `empty` etc...)
Also I should mention that the `real` expression that you want, is captured in group 1
(Read about capture group in regex)